# Llenar tabla PHP

Tags: php, html

Estimados amigos buen dia;

Como puedo llenar una tabla horizoantal mente, resulta que tengo una base de datos con con la informacion de una fechas de una citas medicas 07/05/2020 8:00 am, necesito poder crear el llenado de una tabla dinamicamente de tal manera que quede este manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <?php  
     $i=0;
     $valores = array("dia 1","dia 2","dia 3","dia 4"); 
     foreach ($valores as $row) {
       echo "<th>".$row."</th>";
       $i++;
     }
     ?>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <?php
   $j=1;
   $min = "00";
   while ( $j <= 6) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>08:".$min."</td>";
    echo "<tr>";
    $j++;
    $min = $min+10;
  }
  ?>
</tr>
```

Agradezco toda su colaboracion
Pero me queda es de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y si agregas 3 td mas cuando llenas las horas que pasa?

Comment: Por cada ciclo del `while` estás imprimiento `<tr><td>contenido</td></tr>`, O sea estas imprimiendo una fila completa de una sola columna por cada iteración. Tienes que colocar los 4 `<td>` dentro de los `<tr>` ya sea manualmente o con otro ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar dentro de tu while tu foreach de los días, esto para que cada que recorres un horario lo agregues a la misma posición que el día.

Ejemplo:

```
   while ( $j <= 6) {

     foreach ($valores as $row) {

        echo "<td>08:".$min."</td>";

     }

   }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Esteban pero basicamente lo intento hacer es generar una agenda para reservar citas como se muestra en la imagen. lo he hecho pero no me lo muestra asi me lo muestra todo lineal es decir verticalmente.

Comment: Hola @MattiasDuran, puedes agregar tú código para ver cómo lo tienes.

Answer (score 0):

también existe la opción que indicaban los compañeros en los comentarios, que es añadir 3 `td` mas.

(Vi que no estaban cerradas las etiquetas tbody ni table y en tbody tenias un tr y dentro de ese tr tenias otro)

Ejemplo:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            $valores = array("dia 1", "dia 2", "dia 3", "dia 4");
            foreach ($valores as $row) {
                echo "<th>" . $row . "</th>";
                $i++;
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $j = 1;
        $min = "00";
        while ($j <= 6) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>08: <?= $min ?></td>
                <td>08: <?= $min ?></td>
                <td>08: <?= $min ?></td>
                <td>08: <?= $min ?></td>
            <tr>
            <?php
            $j++;
            $min = $min + 10;
        }
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```